# objects do not block shadow that goes to shadow catcher

Tags: rendering, shadows

I'd like to render only the vase and shadow to then overlay on other shelves and walls, and then do the same with other objects besides the vase.

[image]

If I set the wall and shelf to "shadow catcher" and uncheck "shadow" from the shelf's ray visibility, I get this.

[image]

I've tried many things and spent countless hours on this, but I can't find a way to have the shelf block the shadow and it's driving me insane. Every single shadow catcher article and video I've seen shows it with a simple plane, and in that case there's obviously not issue...

Is there a way to get it right in this scenario? I can only assume there's a way to substract the shelf shadow for the vase shadow, but if there is, I haven't found it ;)

Any help will be appreciated.

Using Blender 2.92 in Cycles.

Update:
My goal is to have 2 images, roughly like these, that I can combine to have the final result. Having many dozens of different shelves, objects and backgrounds, I thought I'd rather try to do it that way rather than render every single combination possible.
[image]

Comment: Hello, could you a diagram of what you would want to appear on the render ? I didn't quite understand your end goal

Comment: Thanks @Gorgious. I've just updated my post with an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I may be missing this... but doesn't a 'Darken' blend on the shadows give you what you want, anyway?

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Where the shadows overlap, it is much darker that the rest. If there were no transparency, this might do the trick, but in this case, it doesn't help.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact that the object on top of the shelf actually contributes to the shadow way further than where you clipped it in your example image. You might get around it by using a blur on the clipping part in compositing mode. Have you tried setting up a plane set to holdout material in the diagonal where you want to clip ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your final goal exactly, but it sounds like if you divide your scene into different render layers you could easily achieve this

Comment: I've tried that, @Gorgious, but I can't manage to get a blur that gives even acceptable results. And expanding a holdout over the diagonal just makes a perfectly straight line as well, so impossible (for me, at least) to combine both images in a realistic way.

Comment: Different render layers don't help, as far as I've been able to test, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, because I still can stop the full shadow of the vase to be cast on the wall. To clarify my end goal. I want to render shelves (or other pieces of furniture), objects such as the vase and wall separately in a way that they can be combined easily, simply to avoid rendering every single image combination. Let's say 20 objects, 20 shelves & 10 background, that's 4k images to render. It grows exponentially with new objects, etc... IF I can make it work by rendering separately, that would be just 50 renders.